# Get the list of Contacts on Windows 10 Phone

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone, uwp, contacts, windows-10-mobile

I am needing to know how to read the contact list on a Windows 10 Phone. I don't want to use a contact picker; I just need to be able to iterate through all contacts to access their name and phone number, and store it in a List. (Similar to how WhatsApp is able to read your contact list and display it in their app)

Comment: Yeah we all want to do this. What have you tried so far? Do you know if an API exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken some code from another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647386/windows-phone-10-is-possible-to-edit-add-new-contact-programmatically-in-wind).

With this code you should be able to get the contacts out.

```
public async Task IterateThroughContactsForContactListId()
 {            
            ContactStore allAccessStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AllContactsReadOnly);

            var contacts = await allAccessStore.FindContactsAsync();
            foreach (var contact in contacts)
            {
                //process aggregated contacts
                if (contact.IsAggregate)
                {
                    //here contact.ContactListId is "" (null....)                  
                    //in this case if you need the the ContactListId then you need to iterate through the raw contacts
                    var rawContacts = await allAccessStore.AggregateContactManager.FindRawContactsAsync(contact);
                    foreach (var rawContact in rawContacts)
                    {
                        //Here you should have ContactListId
                        Debug.WriteLine($"aggregated, name: {rawContact.DisplayName }, ContactListId: {rawContact.ContactListId}");
                    }
                }
                else //not aggregated contacts should work
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"not aggregated, name: {contact.DisplayName }, ContactListId: {contact.ContactListId}");
                }
            }

}
```

He also notes:

> And very important: In the appxmanifest you have to add the contacts
>   capability. Right click to it in the solution explorer and "View Code"
>   and then under Capabilities put
>
> ```
> <uap:Capability Name="contacts" />
> ```
>
> There is no UI for this. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732418/contactmanager-requeststoreasync-throws-system-unauthorizedaccessexception).

Comment: Thank you, that is just what I needed and its working just fine.