# How to get contact list from uwp c#?

Tags: c#, uwp

How can I get the full contact list from user's phone in UWP?

I have found articles on msdn, but thes use only contact picker that doesn't gives me a full list of the contacts. I just would like to get their names and profile images, noting else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ContactStore.FindContactsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn624862.aspx)

```
var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
var contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();
```

Comment: ...and please don't forget to add proper capability in your manifest:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732418/contactmanager-requeststoreasync-throws-system-unauthorizedaccessexception/48836121#48836121